# How to use for loop including files in jade (pug)?

Tags: for-loop, include, pug

I would like to use a for loop to include jade files each after the other such as slide-1, slide-2, slide-3 etc.

I tried this but it failed:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  include('slide-' + i)
}
```

What's the correct syntax?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to iterate a certain number of times, you'd need to define your own function to do so.

```
html
  title Whatup
  -function range(start, end) {
  -    var arr = [];
  -    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) arr.push(i);
  -    return arr;
  -  }
  each i in range(1, 4)
      include('slide-' + i)
```