# How I do for include all files a directory in a .pug file?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a directory with some files and I want include all files this directory in one .pug file.

Comment: Just HTML-files?

Comment: I only have Pug files in directory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include Pug-files into another, you can use `include`:

```
doctype html
html
  include includes/head.pug
  body
    h1 Content
    include includes/body/content.pug
    h1 Footer
    include includes/body/footer.pug
```

[Read more about includes](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html). Take also a look at [Template Inheritance](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html).

**Edit: fixed typo**

Comment: I want to know if exists some way that include all files, for example: `include layout/*.pug`

Comment: Mmh. I am not sure. You could try to use a loop or something similar to include all the files. However, you'll still need to provide the names of the target files. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967240/how-to-use-for-loop-including-files-in-jade-pug), and [here](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html). There might be a way to get the names automatically.